# DeviceType does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

I have a simple restore function. But the problem, is that DeviceType could not be found. I checked my namespaces and they seem to be the only ones I need. Maybe even more. Is there  something wrong?

> The name 'DeviceType' does not exist in the current context

```
public void RestoreDatabase(String databaseName)
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        var connection = new ServerConnection(connectionString);
        var sqlServer = new Server(connection);

        var rstDatabase = new Restore();
        rstDatabase.Database = databaseName;
        rstDatabase.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
        rstDatabase.Devices.AddDevice(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "GC.bak", DeviceType.File);
        rstDatabase.ReplaceDatabase = true;
        rstDatabase.SqlRestore(sqlServer);
    }
```

Here is my Namespaces

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
```

**UPDATE**

I try to build my application and these are the warnings and errors that come up

[image: Errors and warnings]

And yes, I do have SmoExtended referenced as well.

Comment: Are the `using` statements in the same file as the `RestoreDatabase` method?

Comment: You sure you add the `Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll` file as well?

Comment: It looks like `DeviceType` is actually defined in Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll.

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot I think thats only true for SQL Server 2005 and .NET 2.0.  If you look at the docs for SQL Server 2008 it references `SmoExtended`

Comment: @SonerGönül yeah man, I did. But with Abe's answer looks like this is an old approach to restoring. Or is it?

Comment: @J.PMasangcay - if you are using `Smo` try switching to `SmoExtended`

Comment: @AbeMiessler only the 2008 version references `SmoExtended`.  The rest do not.  Not sure what to make of that, but I would lean towards the 2008 version being a documentation bug.

Comment: @AbeMiessler I do have SmoExtended in my references. Is there an alternate way to restore a .bak file to a  database instead of using AddDevice?

Comment: I would start off by commenting out that code and getting the *rest* of it to compile without any errors due to conflicting versions of assemblies.